# Replace Windows newline character in Go

Tags: string, go, replace

Trying to replace windows line ending using `strings.Replace`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

var hw string = "hello\r\nworld"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(hw)
    strings.Replace(hw, "\r\n", " ", -1)
    fmt.Println(hw)
}
```

I suppose it is something very simple I am missing but not sure why the above does not work.

Comment: ....and the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just printing the same `string` value twice. [`strings.Replace()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace) returns you the result which you just discard (you don't do anything with it). Store the result e.g. to the same variable:

```
fmt.Println(hw)
hw = strings.Replace(hw, "\r\n", " ", -1)
fmt.Println(hw)
```

Output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HM25PdgWuMg)):

```
hello
world
hello world
```

Comment: duh, yep that's it I copied some old code and forgot I was not assigning the value. Thx